# Exporting Users From Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to customize columns in Azure DevOps --> Organization Settings --> Users page. Currently we have Name, Extensions, Access Level, Last Access. I need to add another column to show whether the user have code read-only access or contributor access.

Answer (score 1):

This page can't be customized as fas as i know. What you want can't be displayed on that site if you have more then one project anyway. If you want to see this organizationwide a better way would be to organize the users in "Organization settings -> Permissions" in groups for readers and contributors

Comment: I shall try Org Setting --> Permission. Thank You. I have 2 projects in my Org. Is there any way to export these columns to Excel (Instead of Customization) Like User Name, Project X, Project Y.. Where Project X and Y will have either Read Only or Contributor.